# Is "go bald" the same as "become bald"?

Tags: verbs

I saw instances of "people go bald" on the web. I guess it should be the equivalent of "people become bald". Can I always use "go" instead of "become"? Like:
Go broken
Go sad

Comment: Idiomatically, people can go insane or become insane, and they can go bald or become bald. But the overlap is not exact. I've never heard someone say that someone else had gone annoying rather than become annoying; and on the other hand, "Gidget becomes Hawaiian" means something different from "Gidget goes Hawaiian."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, no, *go* is not a universal substitute for *become*.  *Go* is idiomatic with certain words:

> Go broke
>   Go for broke
>   Go crazy
>   Go silent
>   Go naked

But with *broken* or *sad*, not so much.

Comment: Food (and people?) can go bad, and things can go wrong, too. :) I'd say they are both very common expressions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Things can go bad and then to worse, but not go **s**ad.

Comment: Let's not go nuts here, folks.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of baldness, I would say yes. As [the definition of bald at TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bald) shows, both usages are valid.

Answer (score 1):

"Go bald" can implicate an active choice or action.  You can say "he decided to go bald" but it does not make much sense to say "he decided to become bald".

Comment: But that's not what the idiom means.  To "go bald" is to have your hair fall out.  Even if one decided they wanted to be bald, there are no (safe) ways to cause such defoliation.

Comment: Perhaps user151232 means "to maintain a shaved head."

Comment: @BrianTung - But that's not what "go bald" means.

Comment: I don't use it that way, true.  But I'm guessing at his meaning.

Comment: People can [go for the bald look](https://www.quora.com/Would-you-go-for-the-bald-look) (Sorry, but I can't upvote twice)

Comment: "Go bald" has multiple meanings.  One is to become bald through a natural process.  The other is to choose to adopt that look (typically maintained by shaving).  This answer refers to that meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this example in merriam-webster dictionary.

He's already starting to go bald. [=to become bald]

Comment: The question is "Can I **always** use "go" instead of "become"?  In some cases you can, like this definition.  But there are other cases where they don't mean the same thing.  So "always" isn't true.