# Go or Get? Why 'get angry' but 'go crazy', 'go crazy' but 'get furious'?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, collocation

To mean 'become + adjective', you sometimes have to say 'go + adjective' and sometimes 'get + adjective'. For instance,

> He got angry.

not *'He went angry.'

> He went crazy.

much more common than 'He got crazy.' But

> He got furious.

not *'He went furious.'

[ngram viewer: He went angry. He got angry. He went crazy. He got crazy. He went furious. He got furious.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20went%20crazy%2Che%20got%20crazy%2Che%20went%20angry%2Che%20got%20angry%2Che%20went%20furious%2Che%20got%20furious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20went%20crazy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20got%20crazy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20got%20angry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20got%20furious%3B%2Cc0)

Any reason for this, any rule, which would make it unnecessary – for the English learner, who does not have an instinct for this – to learn adjective by adjective which verb they collocate with?

Michael Swan's explanation in *Practical English Usage*, Oxford University Press, Second edition, Fourth impression, 1996, is not really satisfactory:

> (page 129, n° 4 b changes of quality)
>
> *Go* (and not usually *get*) is used before adjectives in a number of common expressions that refer to changes for the worse. People *go mad/crazy/deaf/blind/grey/bald*; […]. Note that we use *get*, not *go*, with *old*, *tired* and *ill*.

Comment: It's the same with *He got upset, He got cross*, where we never use the "spatial metaphor" versions *He went upset, He went cross*. But note that at least some people (incl. me) would draw a potential distinction between *He got mad* and *He went mad* in many contexts. Perhaps the rationale behind *that* would shed some light.

Comment: I'd have to think about it overnight but at first glance, well, you just gotta go crazy and learn a few of them. I think that changes-for-the-worse idea is worth pursuing....

Comment: There's also **turned** as in "He turned ugly" or "She turned mean"

Comment: @barbecue: turned = go, or get? Doesn't solve the problem, only avoids it!

Comment: @Lambie: getting angry or furious is also a change for the worse, and you sitll do not use 'go', don't you?

Comment: @user58319 You can get angry [or any other state or emotion], get happy, get rich, get annoyed etc. go is only for the negative. I can't think of a GO + a happy state except when go crazy means happy.

Comment: I suspect a partial answer is to be found in the distinction between "he got mad" and "he went mad."

Comment: Related: [Is “go bald” the same as “become bald”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292993)

Comment: **go  4** *no object*, *with complement* Pass into or be in a specified state, especially an undesirable one.  ‘the food is going bad’
‘no one went hungry in our house’ ‘he's gone crazy’ (note the "especially" part). https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go

Comment: All of the above examples can be expressed by 'became'. And I think that is the best way to express them, myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the choice between 'go' and 'get' to collocate with an adjective obeys two criteria:

**1)** whether the adjective is **gradable** or **extreme**:

> you ***go** bananas*, not * *get bananas* because you cannot be * *very bananas*, only *completely bananas* (**extreme** adjective)

whereas

> you ***get** angry*, not * *go angry*, because you can be *very angry* (**gradable** adjective)…

but that's not enough, because why then would you

> *get furious*, not * *go furious*, when you cannot be * *very furious*, only *completely furious* (extreme adjective)?

So it must also depend on something else:

**2)** whether the adjective expresses a quality you can have **control** of/over **or not**

> you ***go** bald* because there's nothing you can do to prevent it; similarly, you *go crazy/bananas* because your anger becomes extreme whether you like it or not; it overwhelms you, you **lose control**

whereas

> you ***get** furious* because you 'allow' your anger to become extreme; you **remain in control**.

To sum up:

> if the adjective is **gradable**, ***get*** (*get old/tired/ill* because you can be *very old/tired/ill*);
>
> if it is **extreme**, ***go***, unless it describes something you can have **control** of/over, in which case you still use ***get***.

Sorry! No grammar books to quote from, just a hunch. (Not that I haven't looked!)

Comment: I disagree with the majority of your premises.  Recently I witnessed my cat enjoying a good roll around on the floor, and I thought it looked like a good stress release and I joined him.  I made a *controlled, conscious* decision to *get* just *slightly* crazy.

Comment: @cobaltduck - Unless you are being obtusely ironic, you just agreed that 'get crazy' works when it is voluntary.

Comment: Alas, as much as I wanted to go with this theory, I can't get in the mood. *Get crazy* isn't popular as a synonym for *go crazy*, but the Ngram viewer attests to it. And the theory doesn't explain why you can *go pale* and *get pale*, which process is generally beyond your control. And you can *go very pale*. Likely you *go bananas* because *get bananas* will confuse insanity with retrieving fruit.

Comment: Also you can _go slightly_ crazy. Pity, the theory was starting to appeal to me. Perhaps it's just one of those things you have to learn, like the gender of words in most european languages?

Comment: While there are doubtless exceptions to the rules of thumb suggested here, and in spite of no supporting references (I wouldn't really know where to start looking either), this seems a good attempt at an answer to me.

Comment: Why go all the way when ODOL has said it all already? See my comment at OP.